# How do I check what band is my ubuntu wifi hotspot creating?

Tags: 22.04, ap-hotspot

I want to know what band is my Ubuntu wifi hotspot creating. My ubuntu version is 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the active channel of your hot-spot is is(*from the terminal*):

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

Another way to list all supported channels as well is(*from the terminal*):

```
iwlist channel
```

A third way that displays information in real-time(*from the terminal*) is [wavemon](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/wavemon.1.html) ... it can be installed like so:

```
sudo apt install wavemon
```

and simply run like so:

```
wavemon
```

On the other hand, [linssid](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/linssid.1.html) is a graphical wireless scanner that can be installed like so:

```
sudo apt install linssid
```